# Adding today date in Table name when using Create Table function in standard sql GBQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I am quite new to GBQ and any help is appreciated it.

I have a query below:

```
#Standard SQL
create or replace table  `xxx.xxx.applications`
as select * from  `yyy.yyy.applications`
```

What I need to do is to add today's date at the end of the table name so it is something like `xxx.xxx.applications_<todays date>`
basically create a filename with Application but add date at the end of the name applications.

I am writing a procedure to create a table every time it runs but need to add the date for audit purposes every time I create the table (as a backup).
I searched everywhere and can't get the exact answer, is this possible in Query Editor as I need to store this as a Proc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL, which hasn't been available in BigQuery.

Comment: I don't think this can be done via bigquery UI.

Comment: why do you want a different table for each day? a date partitioned table might work better

Comment: What is your  goal? If you need to create a partitioned table with today's date, you can use a table partitioned by ingestion time

Answer (score 0):

`BigQuery` doesn't support dynamic SQL at the moment which means that this kind of construction is not possible.
Currently `BigQuery` supports [Parameterized Queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) but its not possible to use parameters to dynamically change the source table's name as you can see in the provided link.

> BigQuery supports query parameters to help prevent SQL injection when
>   queries are constructed using user input. This feature is only
>   available with standard SQL syntax. Query parameters can be used as
>   substitutes for arbitrary expressions. Parameters cannot be used as
>   substitutes for identifiers, column names, table names, or other parts
>   of the query.

If you need to build a query based on some variable's value, I suggest that you use some script in `SHELL`, `Python` or any other programming language to create the SQL statement and then execute it using the [bq](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference) command.

Another approach could be using the `BigQuery` [client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) in some of the supported languages instead of the bq command.